# Remove solid coloured background of image

Tags: android, image, camera, chromakey

I want to implement a functionality where user can **capture image through camera and remove the solid background (green/blue)**.
 I have already used *chroma key* inorder to remove background but it is not upto the mark.*Chroma key removing image color also and image quality is disturbed*. 
I have searched a lot to get better option but couldn't find it.If any one has idea to remove background color please share with us.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple, and here is a example for image view to get pixels from image and inside if condition you can replace any pixel with a transparent pixel.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
if(pixel == Color.RED){
    textViewCol.setText("It is RED");
}
```

Also use a for loop to iterate over the entire bitmap.